# Tkinter: using return for widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have been having trouble figuring out what does `return` do when used for tkinter widgets

here are 3 blocks of code that have the same result, and I wasn't sure what their difference is and whether they differ in performance, and finally, which one is the standard approach

1

```
import tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        self.label_in_window(window, text = "hello world!")
        window.mainloop()

    def label_in_window(self, parent, text):
        return tk.Label(parent, text = text).pack()
App()
```

2

```
import tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        self.label_in_window(window, text = "hello world!")
        window.mainloop()

    def label_in_window(self, parent, text):
        tk.Label(parent, text = text).pack()
        return
App()
```

3

```
import tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        self.label_in_window(window, text = "hello world!")
        window.mainloop()

    def label_in_window(self, parent, text):
        tk.Label(parent, text = text).pack()
App()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: If you want to return the widget, none of the methods above work. You should instead use `label = tk.Label(...); label.pack(); return label`

Comment: Actually I don't want to return the widget, I just want it to show the widget

Comment: Ok then all the examples are identical in functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per code answer:

1. does not make sense, because you are returning something, but then throwing the returned result away.
2. you can remove the `return` statement because all functions by default return `None`, and a `return` statement without a value also returns `None`. This then makes 2. and 3. equal.
3. If you just want to put the creation of widgets into a separate function, use the 3rd code.

Anyways, all the returns do not make sense in your code, because they will always return `None`. Guess why ? No ? I'll explain it. It's because of this line:

```py
tk.Label(parent, text = text).pack()
```

First you create a `tk.Label` object. Then, you call its `pack` method which of course returns `None`. So in the end, you have not a `tk.Label`, but a `None`. To change this, you should first assign your `tk.Label` object to a variable, then call the `pack` method *of the variable*, then return the variable:

```py
    def label_in_window(self, parent, text):
        label = tk.Label(parent, text=text)
        label.pack()
        return label
```

But, if you are not planning to use the label later (set a new text, for example), it doesn't make sense to return the label. If you *do* want to use it later, the standard approach in a class would be to assign the label to an attribute of your class. Also, you should move the `window.mainloop` out of the class, and functions / methods should be named after what they *do*, not which result they produce:

```py
import tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.add_label(self.window, text="hello world!")

    def add_label(self, parent, text):
        self.label = tk.Label(parent, text=text)
        self.label.pack()

app = App()
app.window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you used:

```py
return tk.Label(parent, text=text).pack()
```

Which creates a label, calls `.pack()` on the label. It returns whatever `.pack()` returns (which is `None`). For more info please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name). So it's identical to:

```py
tk.Label(parent, text=text).pack()
return None
```

---

The second example uses:

```py
tk.Label(parent, text = text).pack()
return
```

Which creates the label. The `return` is the same as `return None`.

---

In the third example uses:

```py
tk.Label(parent, text=text).pack()
```

Which creates a label then returns `None`.

---

Therefore, all the examples that you have shown are exactly the same. They all create a label and return `None`.

PS: If you use `from dis import dis` and then `dis(App.label_in_window)`, you will see the decompiled bytecode, which is what python actually uses to run your code.